# How to set width of child element to full width rather than 'visible' width (clipped by overflow-x: auto)

Tags: html, css, scroll

Please take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eKJAj/37/. The HTML is simple: a 'container' scrollable element that has a 'parent' child, which in turn has 'bar' and 'content' children. The 'content' element's width is dynamic, but has been set to be equal to the 'container''s width + 100px for this example. I've copied the most relevant bits from the CSS here:

```
.container {
    max-width: 300px;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.parent {
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
}

.bar {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}

.content {
    width: 400px;
}
```

As you can see in Fiddle, when you scroll to the right, the width of the red bar is limited by the width of the 'parent' element, whose width in turn seems to be set to be the 'visible' width, i.e., the width that is not clipped by the 'container' element. Just look at the yellow background and you will see that is the case.

What I want to accomplish is that the red bar continues all the way to the right, which only seems to be possible if the parent element also continues all the way to the right (fully enclosing the 'content' child), instead of having its width limited by the scroll 'viewport'.

Anyone have some ideas to accomplish this using CSS? I'd prefer not to use jQuery or something like that. I think this should be doable with CSS only. It's unfortunately not possible to set a fixed width for the 'parent' element (that would be a very easy solution ...), since the width of the 'content' element is dynamic (and may be even less than the width of the 'container' element). Neither can the 'bar' element be moved into the 'content' element, it needs to be a direct child of the 'parent' element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a `div` to take the entire `widht` of the content you will need to change the `block` behavior. Try this:

```
.parent {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Check the **[UpdatedFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eKJAj/39/)**

Comment: Thanks! I figured regular 'blocks' also scaled to the contents of their children.